# How to add a Windows-like weblink in Xcode for OS X?

Tags: macos, url, xcode4.2, label, nstextfield

In Windows system, a usual web link is like a underlined, blue text. 
When clicking it, it will lead you to a web browser and open the website.

However, I did not find a perfect way to create the same effect in Xcode.

This is how I do currently:

First of all, here is a part of a custom table. Each line repersents a subview, while there is a blue background at the bottom of it. The blue background appears(bye setting a blue image) when mouse-in and displeared(by setting a white image) when mouse-out. Here is the visual effect:

[Image, click me](http://img3.douban.com/view/photo/photo/public/p1882530418.jpg)


And when mouse is on the "Connect" label, the mouse should change its own appearance into a "finger" like the a normal weblink:
[Image, click me](http://img3.douban.com/view/photo/photo/public/p1882562193.jpg)

I subclassed NSTextField and overwrite the **mouseDown:** and **mouseUp:** method to make the label clickable. But I have no idea how to change the mouse appearance...


Any suggestions? Thank you all very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution. Follow the sample code: [DragItemAround](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
Using the method *addCursorRect:cursor:*

Besides, subclass the NSTextField and capture the *mouseDown:* method to implement click action.